# Trying to use OOP for bouncing ball in pong game

Tags: python, oop, pygame

So recently I got into OOP, which is a very new topic for me, and I had already made a pong game that did not employ objects and I'm thinking of doing a new script with objects utilised. The problem is, when I run the code, it displays an empty screen and I'm not sure what I did wrong (I'm still new to OOP). Can anyone help out?

```
import pygame

class Ball():
    def __init__(self, x, y, xmove, ymove, color, size):

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.xmove = 0
        self.ymove = 0
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.size = 10

    def draw(self, screen):

       pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y], self.size)

    def ballmove(self):

        self.x += self.xmove
        self.y += self.ymove

done = False

pygame.init()
WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

ball = Ball(0, 0, 1.5, 1.5, [255, 255, 255], 10)

while done != False:

    screen.fill(0)
    ball.ballmove()
    ball.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used a wrong condtion in your loop. It should mean `while done == False:` or `while done != True:`

Also your constructor is wrong. The parameter you give to the ball will never set, because you initialized all paramters with default values. Use this constructor instead

```
    def __init__(self, x, y, xmove, ymove, color, size):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xmove = xmove
        self.ymove = ymove
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
```

Comment: Omg you're right! I just read a tutorial book and i got confused with setting default values and assigning variables with attributes. Thank you so much!! :D